# override getView in ArrayAdapter and still keep check boxes?

Tags: android, checkbox, android-arrayadapter

I have overrode the `getView()` method in `ArrayAdapter`. I was wondering if there was a way to keep the check box functionality when overriding `getView()`?

With my current implementation, it only shows the image and the text on each row. It no longer shows the checkboxes that were there before overriding.

Below is my code:

```
public class ShortcutsArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ResolveInfo> {

    private final Activity context;
    private final List<ResolveInfo> objects;
    private PackageManager pm = null;

    public ShortcutsArrayAdapter(Activity context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<ResolveInfo> objects, PackageManager pm) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.objects = objects;
        this.pm = pm;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null, true);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        textView.setText(objects.get(position).loadLabel(pm));
        try {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(((BitmapDrawable) pm.getApplicationIcon(objects.get(position).activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName)).getBitmap());
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return rowView;
    }

}
```

---

And here is how i am creating the adapter:

```
    appList = getApplicationList();
    setListAdapter(new ShortcutsArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, appList, pm));
    getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

---

Here is the row layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >  

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"/>

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:text="@+id/label"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you call super.getView() and after that do some of the custom stuff you want to do?
In any case, I don't see why the checkbox shouldn't show. Maybe it is hidden behind another component. Have you checked the layout? Try moving it before or after the text box.

You may need a checkbox in your row_layout.xml. Something like the following:

```
<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/check"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px" >
    </CheckBox>
```

Comment: When adding `super.getView(position, convertView, parent);` to the method. This is the error i get from logcat when running. `02-14 15:44:48.924: E/AndroidRuntime(26397): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView`. I changed it to some random `TextView` and it still did not work. It said `invalid resource`.

Comment: @prolink007 Where is the checkbox in your row_layout.xml :)  ??

Comment: OoooooooooopSSSSS! Forgot to put the Checkbox in my xml. More eyes the better. Thank you.